# Image classification using quantum variational circuit?

Tags: machine-learning, variational-quantum-algorithms

Image classification using variational quantum circuit is described in [here](https://medium.com/predict/classification-using-vqc-with-custom-variational-ansatz-c7c45fb699a1).

3 image clusters having clearly separable 3 feature coordinates have been chosen to be:

[image]

There are classical clustering methods to do this classification.

However, in this method the 3 feature coordinates are fed into a 3 qubit circuit:

[image]

I am rather confused at this point, since each of $q_0, q_1, q_2$ has two parameters

$$q_0 = a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle$$
$$q_1 = c|0\rangle + d|1\rangle$$
$$q_2 = e|0\rangle + f|1\rangle$$

and the feature coordinates only contain 3 numbers, eg. [1.5, 9.3, 0.6]... what number gets inputed into which field in the above set $a, b, c, d, e, f$?

Is anyone familiar with what's going to be the output of this circuit, how to read the results, what is being tuned, and how does this circuit overall perform a classification into 3 labels? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

"Easy" data set seems readily classifiable by the above circuit (optimization rounds 1, 10, 100, 1000)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Since total error calculations require explicit access to all state vector probabilities, it is not clear **how** will cost calculations be performed using a real quantum circuit.